# Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I am developing a page to search for gifs and I get the error when I search for a larger amount of gifs than I asked for the first time, for example if I ask for 15 gisf and then another 15 different gifs I get no error but if I ask for 15 and then 30 the error appears.

The gif grid component:
`

```
function Gifs(props: any) {
    return (
        <div className="gifs-container grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-4 gap-5 ">
            {props.gifList.map((gif: gif, index: number) => {
                const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
                return (
                    //img container
                    <div
                        className="gif-box w-[200px] h-[150px] relative text-white"
                        key={index}
                    >
                        {/* Image */}
                        <img
                            src={gif.url}
                            alt={gif.title}
                            className="w-full h-full object-cover"
                        />
                        {/* Image overlay */}
                        <div
                            className="img-overlay absolute w-full h-full opacity-0 top-0 flex flex-col
                                items-center bg-[rgba(0,0,0,0.6)] transition duration-100 hover:opacity-100
                               justify-around overflow-hidden"
                        >
                            {/* Overlay Tittle */}
                            <div className="overlay-tittle font-bold text-xl text-center w-[80%]">
                                {notGif(gif.title)}
                            </div>
                            {/* Overlay Buttons */}
                            <div className="overlay-buttons grid-cols-2  w-[40%] flex justify-between items-center">
                                <button
                                    className="viewLink w-8 h-8 hover:opacity-60"
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        window.open(gif.url, "_blank");
                                    }}
                                ></button>
                                <div className={`copyMessage ${active ? "active" : ""}`}>
                                    <button
                                        className="copyLink w-9 h-9 hover:opacity-60"
                                        onClick={() => {
                                            navigator.clipboard.writeText(gif.url);
                                            setActive(true);
                                            setTimeout(() => {
                                                setActive(false);
                                            }, 500);
                                        }}
                                    ></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                );
            })}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Gifs;
```

`the app component:`

```
function App() {
    const [gifList, setGifList] = useState<gif[]>([]);
    const [gifCuantity, setGifCuantity] = useState("Cantidad");
    const [gifName, setGifName] = useState("");
    const setGifCuantityF = (newGifCuantity: string) => {
        setGifCuantity(newGifCuantity);
    };
    const setGifNameF = (newGifName: string) => {
        setGifName(newGifName);
    };
    const setGifListFun = (newGifList: gif[]) => {
        setGifList(newGifList);
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        if (gifCuantity !== "Cantidad" && gifName !== "") {
            getGfifs(gifName, gifCuantity, setGifListFun);
            setGifCuantity("Cantidad");
        }
    }, [gifName]);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <div className="h-screen ">
                <div className="mx-auto flex flex-col justify-center items-center gap-8">
                    <Title />
                    <Browser
                        gifCuantity={gifCuantity}
                        setGifCuantityF={setGifCuantityF}
                        setGifNameF={setGifNameF}
                    />
                    {/* <Cgifs gifList={gifList} /> */}
                    <Gifs gifList={gifList} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

`

i think the main proble is on the gifList useState, this is the useState that will contain all the gifs i fetch, so if the useState had array had 15 boxes and then i fetch for 20 gifs the error will say that the 5 new boxes were null before an now they are a useState

Comment: No, the problem is in the state you are defining in `Gifs` return statement, inside the `map` method callback. Don't do that. States and all other hooks have to be declared at the top level of the component's body, before the return statement.

Comment: Thanks man i love u <3<3<3